# Is there any formal test for linear separability of 2-class data?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

SVM is designed for two-class classification problem. If the data is not linear-separable, a kernel function is used. I want to know  if there is exists any method that will indicate if the data is linearly separable or not.

Comment: I think perception Learning algorithm states that if data is linearly separable then the classifier will converge or find a decision boundary giving a 100% classification accuracy. So if you run a basic perception learning algorithm and it converges, data is linearly separable.